# Check the argument in Fish script?

Tags: fish

```
#!/usr/bin/fish

if count $argv > /dev/null
or not test -d $argv[1]
    echo 'Expected a directory.'
    exit 1
end
```

I want to check if the argument is a directory and have searched and edited the code many times, but the code above doesn't run as expection still...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count` returns a true status if it gets at least one argument.

So

```
if count $argv > /dev/null
or not test -d $argv[1]
```

will enter the if-branch if either `$argv` contains something, or `test -d $argv[1]` fails.

The first of these is already wrong, you want

```
 if not count $argv > /dev/null
 or not test -d $argv[1]
```

Which will enter the if-branch if no arguments were given or the first argument isn't a directory.

Now, because of `test`'s issues the bug will manifest weirdly, because:

```
count $argv
or test -d $argv[1]
```

will only run `test -d` if there is no `$argv[1]`, so it will run the equivalent of `test -d` without any additional argument. And because fish's test strictly follows POSIX (one of the few parts of fish to do so), that returns true so you can check things like `test "$var"` as a short form for `test -n "$var"`.